# Student visa for Mongolia refused: is it a good idea to re-apply a year later?

Tags: visa-refusals, study, mongolia

I fell in love with this country and in the middle of 2016, I applied for a student visa for Mongolia.

First, they refused my visa and said to come with a tourist visa and talk with them. Then, they said that the school where I applied is not a real school (but a lot of people got the same visa fror the same school). They don't want to put in writing anything about why they really refused my visa. I tried to call my country's embassy (Spain, I come from EU) with no success; they can't help me.

Should I re-apply? If they already refuse one time, is it possible that they will refuse again? I want to apply to a university there that has a very good program, not a private school to avoid another mess. Still, it seems very weird that they refuse a visa for Mongolia without any explanation. Is this a common problem in Mongolia?

Comment: Is it a real school?

Comment: They show me their certificates, and they have a lot of student there now, most koreans.

Comment: What is the name of School?